# School network and raspberry pi

Tags: networking

I have 20 raspberries and I would like to do different task with my Y5-Y6 here are some of them:

Remote cars would be great but I haven't found WIFI based so we can use more than 5 cars in the same time

I also thought to build a server farm based on functionality (file server, game server, login server, webserver, email server) so children will be able to see what is 'the    cloud' it should work but only as a test environment

using GPIO's with LEDs and sensors so we can collect weather data all around the school    and see it somewhere...

visitors registering with small printer lunch

menu voting system/happiness voting system:)

What is the best network solution for these in a typical school? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a private router network for the various Pies. For remote control cars, I would take a look at this: http://www.dawnrobotics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-camera-robot-chassis-bundle/

Answer (score 1):

The best network would be to use a switch. 100mb/s is fine since that is the fastest a Pi can go plus they are allot cheaper, for 10 or 20 port unmanaged switched. Look on eBay.

You could go wireless but you might get problems with wireless on the Pi, just in general I find it very flakey, but 1 Wireless access point is cheaper than a 20 port switch, but you also have to get 20 Wireless USB dongles that work well on the Pi's USB, that might cost more than a switch.

You can create a load balanced webserver [using this tutorial.](http://raspberrywebserver.com/raspberrypicluster/raspberry-pi-cluster.html) or also do something with [own cloud](http://www.owncloudbook.com/owncloud-on-raspberry-pi/) or a [cluster of own cloud](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/pi_supercomputer_southampton.htm)

It would be nice to setup a cluster of Pi's managed by an interface where you can create and destory Virtual Private servers, like in tens or twenties VPS's at the same time but I don't think it is that simple on the Pi. There is [something for Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-beowulf-cluster-using-ubuntu-12-04-vps-instances)

Other project are more stand alone. You could also try 433mhz communications, as they are very cheap and distance is good but don't expect to send lots of bianry data, more like text based commands, like JSON. To remote things like weather stations or wireless toy cars. Depends on your country but you might also be able to boost the signal on these to increase range.

[I wrote a book about various server like things you can do with a Pi](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Raspberry-Server-Essentials-Piotr-Kula/dp/1783284692/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1393714185&sr=8-1&keywords=raspberry%20pi%20server%20essentials) with some side line ideas. But they are many more articles and books out ther.

Answer (score 1):

We setup a web server at school already. However, my school has 3 different networks. One for administrator one for students, and another that is experimental for us students in the engineering department. We picked a few ports in the IT department, where I work, and traced them back to the server room. We made sure these ports were connected to the experimental network so we could do what we wanted too and NOT be throwing up flags in the system.

When then obviously used a hardline connection to our pi and was able to ssh into our pi's from our own computers for any terminal work we needed to do. You can also download and install the xrdp (windows remote desktop protocal) on your pi and be able to even get into the GUI if you needed to. You'll need a remote desktop program on your computer though. I have a macbook so the apple store has a Microsoft Remote Desktop App that works great. I even use it to remotely fix software and networking errors on all the staff employees computers.

We installed Apache2 and made our own web server when in return spiced up the web link using some easy html coding. We made some shell scripts that we had the web link point to on the pi to light up a simple LED. So now we can be anywhere in the building on a computer or on your phone and go to that url and turn on a LED. Pretty simple but this is how we setup something simple at first with our networks. Were hoping to get alittle more crazy now since we have stuff working.

Comment: Shane C. Yost do you have a blog on how you setting up the servers? quite an interesting work. I am looking for a way to help the rural area school in utilising the raspberry pi. Hope you willing to share.